# How do I reference different model types from one field in Django?

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

I have a model representing a `Log Entry`. This is created anytime there is a modification to the DB.

I would like to include a foreign key field which refers to the model object that was changed in the `Log Entry`.

Is such a thing possible?

For example:

```
Log Entry 1

---> Modified Object Field = User Object
```

But now instead of User being modified, Blog was modified...

```
Log Entry 2

---> Modified Object Field = Blog Object
```

Comment: Your best guess is to look up how django admin does the same thing. You have noticed your log, when you log into django admin, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations):

> A normal ForeignKey can only “point to” one other model [...] The contenttypes application
>   provides a special field type (GenericForeignKey) which works around
>   this and allows the relationship to be with any model.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using generic relations and the `GenericForeignKey`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Keep in mind it becomes more involved to filter across the generic foreign key ( you need to get the foreignkey content types first)

Answer (score 0):

You can use as  **Nigel Tufnel** says a `GenericForeignKey`  but I think you are looking for something like the `Django's admin log`, if you take around the `Django's` code you can see that it  uses a `ForeignKey` to `ContentType` and a message:

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(_('action time'), auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.TextField(_('object id'), blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(_('object repr'), max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('action flag'))
    change_message = models.TextField(_('change message'), blank=True)
```

Comment: But that's what a generic foreign is. The actual class just adds a bit of sugar on top of the content type/object id fields.